# SQL Left outer join on 3 tables

Tags: sql

I was trying to join 3 tables but the result show the column is empty data. please refer to below details and kindly advise the situation. Appreciate it!

What table i Have:

```
1) EXPORT_SHIPMENT
SHPMNT_REF  UPDATE_USER    TYPE
1002            A           CS
1003            B           CA 

2) EXPORT_ONHAND
ONHAND_REF  UPDATE_USER     TYPE   SHPMNT_REF
 50001           A           CS      1002
 50002           B           CA      1003 

3) VW_EXPORT_EVENT_VCB
 FILE_NO    VCB_FA_CREATED_TIME
 50001        2018-07-26          
 50002        2018-07-25
```

What I did as below:

```
SELECT 
    ES.SHPMNT_REF,
    V.VCB_FA_CREATED_TIME
FROM 
    EXPORT_SHIPMENT ES 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT 
         OH.ONHAND_REF,
         VCB.FILE_NO,
         VCB.VCB_FA_CREATED_TIME
     FROM 
         EXPORT_ONHAND OH 
     INNER JOIN 
         VW_EXPORT_EVENT_VCB VCB ON OH.ONHAND_REF = VCB.FILE_NO) AS "V" ON ES.SHPMNT_REF = V.ONHAND_REF
WHERE
    ES.SHPMNT_REF <> '1001'
```

The "V.VCB_FA_CREATED_TIME" column is empty data after I run this code.

What I want to see in the result is:

```
SHPMNT_REF    VCB_FA_CREATED_TIME
1002               2018-07-26
1003               2018-07-25
```

Please assist. Much appreciated!

Comment: Because you are doing `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on tables it is showing `NULL` values for the data rows which dont have matching rows in `"V"`. If you want only matching rows then change `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`.  [here read more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt8wzxy4.aspx)

Comment: Hi @CoderofCode, I was changed the  'LEFT OUTER JOIN' to 'INNER JOIN', but the result still same.

Comment: What do you mean by "The "V.VCB_FA_CREATED_TIME" is shown after i run this code"?

And do you have some examples of the data - can you just supply some that you expect to see displayed, i.e. EXPORT_SHIPMENT (SHPMNT_REF), EXPORT_ONHAND  (ONHAND_REF) and VW_EXPORT_EVENT_VCB  (FILE_NO, VCB_FA_CREATED_TIME).  

I'm still not sure what you're expecting nor what you're actually seeing.

Comment: @monty sorry that should be "not showing any data", I have modified the question. Thanks,

Comment: @CKAng In LEFT OUTER JOIN, left side table will be having all the rows displayed and only matching rows from right side displayed. As VCB_FA_CREATED_TIME is coming from right table, if the right table has matching rows, and not null value for VCB_FA_CREATED_TIME, then you will have not null value. Otherwise, it will be NULL.

Comment: Can you please create a minimal verifiable example and host it on a service like https://www.db-fiddle.com/ so we can get a better look at your problem together with data that will recreate it.

Comment: Guys sorry to make u confused, I have create an example as above. Thanks!
@ajxs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below Query

```
select ES.SHPMNT_REF,T.VCB_FA_CREATED_TIME from EXPORT_SHIPMENT ES 
  left join

  (
    select * from EXPORT_ONHAND EO
   inner join   
  VW_EXPORT_EVENT_VCB VW on EO.ONHAND_REF=VW.FILE_NO
    )
   as T 

  on ES.SHPMNT_REF=T.SHPMNT_REF
```

see below link

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/i7mmehTxD8kh2h5BHeCdEi/1

Comment: @ck Ang does it helps?

Comment: btw, my "SHPMNT_REF" will duplicate if using this method, do you know how to solve it?

Comment: just use distinct

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
 SELECT 
        ES.SHPMNT_REF,
        V.VCB_FA_CREATED_TIME
    FROM 
        EXPORT_SHIPMENT ES 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (SELECT 
             OH.SHPMNT_REF,
             VCB.FILE_NO,
             VCB.VCB_FA_CREATED_TIME
         FROM 
             EXPORT_ONHAND OH 
         INNER JOIN 
             VW_EXPORT_EVENT_VCB VCB ON OH.ONHAND_REF = VCB.FILE_NO) AS V 
             ON ES.SHPMNT_REF = V.SHPMNT_REF
    WHERE
        ES.SHPMNT_REF <> '1001';
```

Comment: Thanks, it's work nicely but it will show duplicate record, do you know how to solve it?